# Swift Error Message with a Firebase completion block

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm getting an error from this code. Is there any way anyone could fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change it to this:

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: { (anonymousUser, error) in

        if error == nil{
            print("UserId : \(anonymousUser?.uid)")
        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
```

Note: You could change your if statement to something like:

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: { (anonymousUser, error) in

        if let err = error{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print("UserId : \(anonymousUser?.uid)")

    })
```

To save you an else and make your code more readable.